# I am getting 403 response code while uploading file in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Am working on one application & i created script using dev tools after uploading file using csv data and everything using http request am getting 403 response code can u pls suggest me about this issue[image: am getting 403 response code after adding all requried fields]

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the response it appears that you fail to pass correct [CSRF Token](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md#token-based-mitigation), please double check your `${csrfmiddlewaretoken}` value using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) combination.

My expectation is that you need to extract this token from each previous request using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) so this variable would have a new updated value each time you use it. Check out [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) article for more details.